# Calculating point coordinates from user tap with constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, geometry, coordinates

I am trying to calculate the coordinates along a circle corresponding to the tap location. The coordinates should be on the border of the circle nearest to the tap location (e.g. the border that is less distant from the radius). To facilitate this I am detecting only taps that are distant by 80% of the radius from the circle center.

[image]

**Input:**

- P (GPPoint) - center of the circle
- P1 (GPPoint)  current position of an image displayed
- r (float) radius of circle
- P3 (CGPoint) user tap coordinate

**Desired output:**

P2 (CGPoint) - new coordinates for the image corresponding to P3 but along the circle. Sorry for the bad explanation, I try to explain it in other words: once the user taps on the screen I would like to move the image in P2. P2 should be derived by moving P2 to the border of the circle. It should be possible to do so by using the radius information.

The idea is to create from P3 coordinates a new coordinate called P2 as described above - the key is that P2   distance from the centre **should correspond exactly to the radius and the ANGLE** should be the same as tapPoint.

Would anyome be able to suggest a formula to calculate the corresponding coordinate given a tap? I simply need to calculate P3 using the input I have.

Code so far:

```
-(void)tapInImageView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap
{
    CGPoint tapPoint = [tap locationInView:tap.view];

    if ([self isInOuternCircle:tapPoint]) {

       // then create from tapPoint coordinates a new coordinate P2 as described above - but have no idea how.. the key is that P2   distance from the centre should correspond exactly to the radius and the ANGLE should be the same as tapPoint.
    }
}

-(BOOL)isInOuternCircle:(CGPoint)point
{
    double distanceToCenter = sqrt((point.x - _timerView.center.x)*(point.x - _timerView.center.x) + (point.y - _timerView.center.y)*(point.y - _timerView.center.y));

    if (distanceToCenter < _innerCircleRadius) {
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this once before, but the math usually depends on how you've set up your coordinate system, so I'll just outline what I did. You'll need a bit of geometry, and a few formulae to determine the new coordinate along the circle.

1. Calculate the formula of a line passing through the center (P) and your tap point (P3) using  this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form
2. Determine the equation for your circle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations
3. Using the above two equations, you'll have a system of a linear and a quadratic equation: http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/systems-linear-quadratic-equations.html

Once you have the equation above, you need to solve it. The result will yield two possible points (the line will intersect the circle in two places), and the point you are looking for is the point closer the tap point. In this case, just compare the distances to P3 between the two solutions, and the shorter distance will show your required solution - P2.